# How to Get Polymer Custom Properties to Work

Tags: css, polymer, angular-dart

The document for the Polymer list-item specifies the following custom property:

--paper-item-focused-before Mixin applied to :before focused paper-items    {}

I'm not sure if the {} means there is no default or "we aren't telling you. The reason I say that it that I found the following in the #shadow-root styling for the selected item:

```
:host(:focus):before, .paper-item:focus:before {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;

    background: currentColor;
    content: '';
    opacity: 0.12;
    pointer-events: none;;
}
```

and this in paper-item-shared-style.html

```
      :host(:focus):before, .paper-item:focus:before {
    @apply(--layout-fit);

    background: currentColor;
    content: '';
    opacity: var(--dark-divider-opacity);
    pointer-events: none;

    @apply(--paper-item-focused-before);
  }
```

So it seems content is being defined for --paper-item-focused-before. Anyway, if I replace currentColor with my desired color in the inspector, it does what I want. I assume the permanent way to change it is to define --paper-item-focused-before. I added this to css in index.html:

```
  <style is="custom-style">
  :host {
    --paper-item-focused-before: {
      background-color: #293040
    }
  }
...
</style>
```

It doesn't work. Do I  have to use a different selector or put in in a different location?

Comment: `host` does not exist inside a `dom tree` it only exists inside `shadow dom`. For normal dom it's `root`. You can also define this value in `class` or `css element selector`

Comment: As for your first question, what it tells you is that value of the `mixin` is empty object right now. It does not tell you anything about the values inside the `class`. The mixin is kept at end in a `style` so that it can overwrite any previously written value. If you move your mixin above any property and then try to overwrite it using mixin it will not work.

Answer (score 0):

@a1626's answer is what fixed it. I had actually tried :root before, but it was the css specified by the component. It works when I put it in style in index.html:

```
<style is="custom-style">
  :root {
    --paper-item-focused-before: {
      background-color: #293040
    }
}
...
</style>
```

This what I got in the inspector in the #shadow-root

```
:host(:focus):before, .paper-item:focus:before {
  position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      right: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 0;

    background: currentColor;
    content: '';
    opacity: 0.12;
    pointer-events: none;background-color: #293040;
}
```

This supports @a1626 answer that --paper-item-focused-before is empty. @a1626, if you choose to answer the question, I'll accept it over mine.